# python module from pypi not installing?

Tags: python, pypi

I am using windows machine python 2.7.I am trying to convert hex to color name.I have downloaded webcolors 1.5 from pypi,When i install it from cmd using

```
python d:\webcolors-1.5\setup.py install
```

I am getting as

```
setup.pyrunning install
running build
running build_py
file webcolors.py (for module webcolors) not found
file webcolors.py (for module webcolors) not found
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\webcolors-1.5-py2.7.egg-info
Writing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\webcolors-1.5-py2.7.egg-info
```

when I run import webcolors it shows no module error.How to correctly install this package?Is it the problem with that 'webcolors' package?

**Edit**
When i install using

```
pip install webcolors
```

I am getting

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): webcolors in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

But it still shows no module error

**Edit**
my code

```
import cv2
from collections import namedtuple
from math import sqrt
import random
import webcolors

def main():
 img = cv2.imread('d:/Emmanu/project-data/bu5.jpg')
 res=cv2.resize(img,(400,300))
 crop_img = res[100:200, 150:250]
 cv2.imwrite("d:/Emmanu/project-data/color-test.jpg", crop_img)

 im = Image.open("d:/Emmanu/project-data/color-test.jpg")
 n, color = max(im.getcolors(im.size[0]*im.size[1]))
 print rgb_to_name(color)
if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Comment: have you tried installing by pip?

Comment: @HarunErgül I have installed pip.

Comment: I used pip and i install it and i can import

Comment: is it possible two show related place in your code

Comment: @HarunErgül ok.You installed using 'pip install webcolors' this command?

Comment: yes i have installed just now

Comment: @HarunErgül Added my code

Comment: i will check your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `pip` command and i installed webcolors.

```
pip install webcolors
```

[image]

And i can import 
[image]

Comment: using pip worked.My problem was i first installed using setup.py and it created Egg.info files in python Lib.That prevented me from installing using pip.I deleted that egg.info files and i reinstalled using pip it worked.Thanks

Comment: Ok. You solved most of your problems. I did nothing.It is your first question  and it is clear